# Profile Generate vs PG

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, profiling, gprof

Can anybody explain to me the difference between `profile-generate` and the `pg` options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both will generate the profile data. But their usage differs.

`fprofile-generate` is to generate the binary with profiling information which you can re-use to give feedback to the compiler when you compile it again with `fprofile-use`.

For example:

```
$ gcc -fprofile-generate filename.c
```

If you execute the binary generated by the about command, it will produce a file called `filename.gcda` with profile data.

When you compile it with `fprofile-use` again:

```
$ gcc -fprofile-use filename.c
```

This time, gcc will use that data from `filename.gcda` to optimize further.

When you execute the binary which was compiled with `-pg`, it'll generate `gmon.out` which can be later used to analyze the code using [`gprof`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) command. This is more like static analysis which will give information about code path.